# SwiftUI - Presenting a ViewController/TableViewController from SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation

The app is still heavily using ViewControllers and TableViewControllers, which is making it difficult to integrate SwiftUI.

Firstly, I'm presenting a swiftUI view from a ViewController.

```
class SwiftUIViewController : UIViewController {

    let contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        view.addSubview(contentView.view)
    }
}
```

Now, from within my **SwiftUIView**, I need to start ViewControllers and TableViewControllers.
I created an injector class that can be used with .sheet to present a view controller from SwiftUI.

```
struct ViewControllerInjector : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let viewController: UIViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return viewController
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
    
    }
}
```

Now this kind of works, the only issue is that I can't seem to find a way to present the ViewController without it being a **.sheet**

```
struct SwiftUIView : View {
    @State private var showingVC1 = false
    ...

    .sheet(isPresented: $showingVC1) {
        ViewControllerInjector(viewController: ViewController1())
    }

    ...
}
```

I would like to completely leave the swift ui screen and continue with the view controller until I press the back button and return to the SwiftUI screen. Also, the injector doesn't seem to work with **TableViewControllers** even if I create a second injector class dedicated to TableView.

Is this type of navigation possible? If anything is not clear, don't hesitate to leave a comment. Thanks

Comment: Probably won't be of much help, but it feels like you wish to simplify. Almost 18 months ago (wow!) I bought into SwiftUI and had a need for something - a UINavigationView with two UITableViews to navigate between. SwiftUI was *so* raw, that when I needed to add an edit button in the navigation for the first UITableView I resorted to a "representable". It was only after I found I needed that for an image picker, a share sheet, and a slide out that I simply gave up. UIKit isn't going anywhere for a decade, maybe two. My advice, don't try too much. Stick with the correct *base* for the app.

Comment: FYI, what I *did* get working was making the entire UIKit piece - a navigation controller, two table views, the first editable - as a UIViewControllerRepresentable. It was only after that I gave up on SwiftUI. (For now.) I think this was the piece I thought that maybe I could something like you are talking about - embed either UIKit into SwiftUI or vice versa, than with the component you are embedding, embed the other. I honestly say I'd suggest you just simplify things. Remember, someday either you or someone else will have to pick up on this code for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue being that .sheet is a modal view and you would like it to be fullscreen? In that case, try replacing **.sheet** with **.fullScreenCover**

To present a TableViewController in SwiftUI, try switching UIViewController to UITableViewController or UITableView. Here's a code snippet I found here some time ago:

```
struct UITableViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
   
        uiTableView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        uiTableView.delegate = context.coordinator

        }

        uiTableView.register(HostingCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        return uiTableView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiTableView: UITableView, context: Context) {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    class HostingCell: UITableViewCell { // just to hold hosting controller
        var host: UIHostingController<AnyView>?
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        init(_ parent: UITableViewRepresentable) {
           
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return self.parent.items.keys.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return parent.items[section]?.count ?? 0
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           
          
            return tableViewCell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer kind sir. Will definitely try this.